# fork() and address spaces

Tags: c, linux, fork

What happens if a call a function that execute the child code?
The address space of the parent process gets copied but parent's local variables can't be used. 
I know that when using fork() the address space gets copied only when a write is made in child or parent process so if a made a write in the parent then the child will get a copy of the parent address space.
Is it okay to put the child code in a separate function?

```
void child(){
    //do something
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int x = 0;
    int pid;
    if((pid=fork()) < 0){
        printf("error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pid==0){
        child();
    }
    x=12;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think "copy on write" is symmetric. It's effectively an unobservable optimization. Just pretend both processes have their own memory (with initially copied contents).

Comment: What programming language is this? C? C++? Something else?

Comment: It seems you understand different processes have distinct address spaces on typical full-size OS. With this, it is not clear what you are asking. How does using a function (wehich does not exist as such in machine code) change anything?

Comment: @JJJ: The programming language is irrelevant, it is an OS issue, because it's asking about run-time behaviour which only uses machine code.

Comment: Read [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) wikipage, [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page, and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) or some other book. Read also [Operating systems: three easy pieces](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/). A book chapter (at least) is needed to answer your question. We don't have that space here.

Answer (score 1):

The child gets a complete copy of the parent's address space.   So the child can access pointers created by the parent, but only things created up to the point before the `fork()`.  After the fork, for all programming purposes, each process has a copy of the parent's memory.  So changes by the parent (or child) are constrained to their own block.

For example, say the parent had a pointer to a character buffer.  The parent `fork()`s, so now both parent and child contain that same pointer to that same block.  If the parent or child change that buffer, the other process does not see the change.  At the hardware level that memory block will be somewhere else.  The process is running in a virtual address space, so when the two programs memory blocks change, that part of the memory (well the whole page) is copied for each process.

It's no problem to put the child code in a function, actually it's a good idea.